# Does populating a Flex children from a function affect performance in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I usually do something like this to Row/Column to elegantly add padding between elements

```dart
Row(
   children: [
   //...
   ].withHorizontalElementsSpacing(8)
),
```

The extension method `withHorizontalElementsSpacing` is part of utility methods I copy/paste from one project to another. Here's a sample of what that file contains:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension ElementsSpacing on List<Widget> {
  List<Widget> _wrapWithWidget(Widget widget) {
    List<Widget> result = [];

    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
      result.add(this[index]);
      if (index != length - 1) {
        result.add(widget);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  List<Widget> withVerticalElementsSpacing([double spacing = 16]) {
    return _wrapWithWidget(SizedBox(height: spacing));
  }

  List<Widget> withHorizontalElementsSpacing([double spacing = 16]) {
    return _wrapWithWidget(SizedBox(width: spacing));
  }

//...
```

Does this behavior affect performance? And how bad?

Comment: it doesn't affect the performance at all

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to use it like that. Although I do believe that using an iterator might make it more efficient. Something like this

```
List<Widget> _wrapWithWidget(Widget widget) {
  return intersperse(widget, this).toList();
}

Iterable<T> intersperse<T>(T element, Iterable<T> iterable) sync* {
  final iterator = iterable.iterator;
  if (iterator.moveNext()) {
    yield iterator.current;
    while (iterator.moveNext()) {
      yield element;
      yield iterator.current;
    }
  }
}
```